# 与えられた仮想アドレスからどのプロセスで使っているかを調べるKernelAPIについて教えてください。

Tags: linux, freebsd, kernel

FreeBSDのAPIで、与えられた仮想アドレスからどのプロセスで使っているかを調べるKernelAPIはありますでしょうか。

もし可能であれば、LinuxのKernel APIでも同様のことができるのか教えていただければと思います。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 仮想アドレスを想定していました。

Comment: 仮想アドレスはプロセス毎に存在するので、仮想アドレスがどのプロセスのものかを尋ねることは無意味です。

Comment: sayuriさんコメントありがとうございます。

Comment: いただいたコメントで、仮想アドレスがどのプロセスのものか調べることが無意味なことはよくわかったのですが、与えられた仮想アドレスが自プロセスにとって有効か調べることは可能だと思ってよろしいでしょうか。FreeBSDだと、vm_map_lookup(http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/9/vm_map_lookup/)を使うのかなと思ったのですが、認識あっていますでしょうか。

Comment: 当初とはまったく別の質問になってしまっていますから、新規に質問し直してはどうでしょうか？

Comment: sayuriさん、コメントありがとうございます。新規に質問直させていただきました。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34464/%E4%B8%8E%E3%81%88%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E4%BB%AE%E6%83%B3%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%8C%E8%87%AA%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E6%9C%89%E5%8A%B9%E3%81%8B%E8%AA%BF%E3%81%B9%E3%82%8Bkernelapi%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84

Comment: マルチポスト　http://q.hatena.ne.jp/1493870803

Answer (score 5):

Win32 では .EXE のロードアドレスは [そのプロセスの仮想記憶域の 0x0040 0000 番地] です。この数値は x86 アーキテクチャの仮想記憶保護機構のページの大きさや Win95 と MS-DOS との互換を保つための仮想 86 モードの実装上の都合などから決まっています。

Linux/FreeBSD でも x86 上では事情は同じなので同じ数値が使われています（のはずです）。

つまりどういうことかというと、
- 仮想アドレスというのはプロセスごとに定義しなおすものである
- プロセス foo 内では仮想アドレス 0x0040 0000 番地は foo.EXE のロード開始位置
- プロセス bar 内では仮想アドレス 0x0040 0000 番地は bar.EXE のロード開始位置
- プロセス baz 内では仮想アドレス 0x0040 0000 番地は baz.EXE のロード開始位置
ということで「異プロセスが同一仮想アドレス値を使う」のはごく普通の話となっています。
もちろん foo と bar で、ロードされている物理メモリは違う場所です。

なので「プロセスを特定しないで」仮想アドレスだけ持ってきても無意味です。

仮想アドレスと物理アドレスの対応表ならなんとなく意味がありそうな気もしますが
- 32bit OS で 4 ギガ単位になる表を得ても巨大すぎて使い道がなさそう
- まして 64bit OS ではテラ単位になってもっと意味がなさそう
- プロセスの、物理メモリ上の位置はいつでも任意に再配置があり得て、過去の調査結果は今と一致しない可能性のほうが高い
あたりの事情によって、調べることができてもおいしくないと思われます。

この質問に至った本当の動機がわかればまた別の回答がつくかもしれません。

Comment: 774RRさん　丁寧なコメントありがとうございました。FreeBSDのドライバーに仮想アドレスが渡された際に、セキュリティー対策として渡された仮想アドレスが不正なものでないかを調べたかったです。自プロセスにとって有効なアドレスかのチェックであれば、F‌​reeBSDだとvm_map_look‌​up(unix.com/man-page‌​/freebsd/9/vm_map_lo‌​okup/)というAPIがあるらしいのですが、このAPIを使ってアドレスチェックをすれば良いのでしょうか？