# 与えられた仮想ア‌​ドレスが自プロセスにとって有効か調べるKernelAPIについて教えてください。

Tags: linux, freebsd, kernel

FreeBSDのAPIで、与えられた仮想ア‌​ドレスが自プロセスにとって有効か調べるKernelAPIはありますでしょうか。

FreeBSDのドライバーに仮想アドレスが渡された際に、ページフォルト対策(セキュリテ‌​ィー対策)として渡された仮想アドレスが不正‌​なものでないかを調べたいと思っています。

個人的に調べた感じでは、vm_map_look‌​_up(http://www.yosbits.com/opensonar/rest/man/freebsd/man/ja/man9/vm_map_lookup.9.html) を使えばよいのかなとも思っているのですが、APIの使い方として適切なのか確信できない為質問させていただきました。

また、もし可能であれば、LinuxのKernel APIでも同様のことができるのか教えていただければと思います。
よろしくお願いいたします。

こちらの質問は、下記の質問中に質問が変わってしまった為、新規に立てさせていただきました。

[与えられた仮想アドレスからどのプロセスで使っているかを調べるKernelAPIについて教えてください。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34450/%E4%B8%8E%E3%81%88%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E4%BB%AE%E6%83%B3%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AE%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%81%A7%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%82%92%E8%AA%BF%E3%81%B9%E3%82%8Bkernelapi%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84)

Comment: マルチポスト　http://q.hatena.ne.jp/1493870803

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: [マルチポスト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/4236)なため

Comment: マルチポストであることがまずかったのですね。空気が読めずにすいませんでした。今後気をつけます。

Comment: マルチポスト先の内容は、正確には、下記の内容と同じでした。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34450/
仮想アドレスが重複する為、質問自体が意味がなかったので、捕捉のコメントをつけさせてもらい、質問をキャンセすさせてもらいました。